# Delete spaces from Editable object

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have deleted characters in edittext objects with this code

```
edit = etcalle.getEditableText();
if (edit.length() > 0)
  edit.delete(edit.length() - 1, edit.length());
```

It has been working but when my string looks like this **+81 901** it doesn't delete the space. It gets to it and stops deleting characters.

How can I remove the space in my text?

**EDIT:**

Just to be clear, I don't want to remove everything at once. Just one character at every time I hit my delete button

Comment: Use `etcalle.getText().toString()` to get the `String` object. use `String.replace(" ", "");` to remove all space characters.

Comment: @user2558882 I still want to delete the `+89` or the `901` if i hit my delete button.

Comment: What happens if you hit delete twice after deleting `9`? Is `1` deleted?

Comment: Works for me. Could you edit the question to contain additional code to make the issue reproducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String original = etcalle.getText().toString();
```

then

```
etcalle.setText(original.substring(0,original.length-1));
```

of course be sure to check that the original is not null or length < 1

Comment: No. ==> `It has been working but when my string looks like this +81 901 it doesn't delete the space`

Comment: @user2558882 use my method to remove the space any where in string

Comment: @Hi-TechKitKatAndroid You code will work. But, `String.replaceAll()` is supposed to be used with `regex` argument. For what OP is trying to do, character replacement with `String.replace()` is sufficient. Please refer to the docs on this.

Comment: @Hi-TechKitKatAndroid Care to explain why?

Comment: as you seen '' single quotes but it works .replace(" ",""); i have edited thanks

Comment: @runor49 it doesn't seem to work. It acts the same as my code does now

Comment: @runor49 your code does work. I just removed the space and then formatted the number to be a phone number so the space got added back. I used your code with a .trim on original. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this it will remove all the spaces

```
String str = "99 85263 9633";
str.replace(" ", "");  // Output is 99852639633
```

Then Its magic you can do this with this

```
String str = "99 85263 9633";
str.replaceFirst(" ",""); // Output is 9985263 9633
```

Comment: I dont want to remove everything at once. Just one character at every time i hit my delete button

Comment: @BigT Do you want this

Comment: @BigT when you repeat second function repeatedly it will remove first occurrence of space